# Is this a log-concave function?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, convexity, convex-optimization

Let $(a_k)$ be a log-concave positive decreasing sequence. Is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k(1-e^x)^{k-1}$ log-concave in $x<0$, for each natural $n$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and under weaker conditions.

Set $s = (1-e^x) > 0$, and multiply your partial sums by $s$; this has no
effect on log concavity. Then the resulting sequence is the Hadamard
product of the coefficients of $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)$ with $(s^n)$, each of
which is log concave (the first is the convolution of $(1,1,1,\dots,)$
with $(a_k)$), so the outcome is.

This argument requires only that $(a_k)$ be log concave (no monotonicity,
etc). [There is a quick reduction to $(a_k)$ being a finite sequence if
you don't like the possibly infinite convolution, since the $n$th partial
sum only involve the first $n$ terms of $(a_k)$, and log concavity is
checked just using the $n-1,n+1,n$th terms for each $n$.]

Edit: The original question has been edited (and not by the original proposer) to be quite different. The answer here is to what I thought was the original question, which was whether $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i (1-e^x)^{n-1})$ is a log concave sequence in $n$.

Comment: Perhaps you understood the question to be about the log-concavity in $n$. However, I believe it is about the log-concavity in $x$; otherwise, indeed, why not use $s$ instead of $1-e^x$? I am now going to edit the question for clarity.

Comment: I think it would be better for the OP to edit it in this case, just to explain what he meant. And now (after editting), the question is ambiguous, because it could mean either (1) as a function of $x$, the function is log concave, or (2) the Maclaurin series coefficients (perhaps with absolute values) is a log concave sequence. In any event, is it usual to talk about log concavity with a negative parameter?

Comment: And *log concave* (no hyphen) is preferred to *log-concave*.

Comment: To answer David's questions: 
For two reasons, I was and am pretty sure that the OP meant the log-concavity in $x$, and not in $n$: (i) if the OP had meant the log-concavity in $n$, then there would have been no reason for him to use $1-e^x$ rather than a simple symbol (say $s$) and (ii) because I had seen a related question by the same OP at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/229028/log-concave-polynomial-is-a-log-concave-function and, especially, his comments there.

Comment: Continued: 
I don't see any ambiguity in the edited question. In particular, I don't see any substantial difference between "log-concave in $x$, for each natural $n$" there and your "(1) as a function of $x$, the function is log concave". I also don't see how the question about the log-concavity in $x$ could be possibly interpreted as a question about the log-concavity of the sequence of the Maclaurin series coefficients.

Comment: Concerning David's question "is it usual to talk about log concavity with a negative parameter?": If you meant "the log-concavity of a function defined on the interval $(-\infty,0)$", why cannot one talk about that? 


Does one need a hyphen in "log-concave"? Wikipedia and the titles of all Related questions on this very page do invariably spell "log-concave" with a hyphen. 


All that said -- anyone, including of course the OP, is free to further edit the question.