# Are polynomials with only real zeros log concave functions?

Tags: polynomials, convexity, convex-analysis

Consider a polynomial $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ with $a_k\geq 0$ and $x\geq 0$.
In this [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229028/log-concave-polynomial-is-a-log-concave-function), [Richard Stanley](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2807/richard-stanley) mentions that polynomials with only real roots are log concave functions. Can somebody provide a reference for this result? I can't find it anywhere. I am in particular interested to know if a similar result holds for multivariate polynomials.

Also, does anybody know other results about the log-concavity of polynomials as functions?

(To be clear I'm **not** talking about log-concave polynomials in the sense that their coefficients form a log-concave sequence.)

Edit: I've added restrictions such that the polynomial is never negative.

Comment: Such polynomials aren't even positive functions, so what is meant with log-convexity?

Comment: What does the question mean? If a polynomial has a real zero, it is generally negative on parts of the real line...

Comment: $\log( (x-a)(x-b))=\log(x-a)+\log(x-b)$ and sum of concave functions is concave, but you have to be careful about the domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This fact is trivial. Your assumptions imply that $$f(x)=ax^m\prod(1+x/x_k),$$
where $a>0$ and $x_k>0$. All zeros $-x_k$ are negative because you assume that
$a_k\geq 0$, so there are no positive zeros. Now every factor in this product is log-concave, therefore the product is log-concave.

Comment: Thanks. Does a result like this exist for multivariate polynomials?

Comment: @MTD: I don't know. At least this is not straightforward. But there is a literature on zeros of multivariate polynomials with positive coefficients.